# How do i install ubuntu on corrupt win 7

Tags: system-installation, bootloader, livedvd

I have an assembled computer. It runs on *Windows 7 Ultimate*. I exactly don't know what  happened but when I switch it on , it says  that "the file checksum does not match the computed checksum".

---

So I thought of installing Ubuntu in it.But it is not happening. I burned the Ubuntu downloaded files on a DVD RW.

I set it to boot using the disc but it said "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key". I did what I can, but I am unable to boot it.

*I need a little help ASAP.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** separate problems here:

- Does the DVD now contain a *bootable* Ubuntu installer. (check how you created the DVD). *You need a bootloader from somewhere.*
- How can you select the DVD drive, to boot from. (*see below*)

---

You need to get the PC to select the correct boot source (your DVD drive).

Best method is MANUAL, not setting boot order.

You need to select whatever key (often <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or <kbd>F10</kbd>) to see BIOS menu. Then select 'manually select boot device' (or similar).

*If you identify the exact motherboard, BIOS, etc. someone can probably tell you exact steps.*

---

Then follow steps as suggested by **@Registered User**.